# rsync - only keep 10 backup folders

Tags: rsync

**TL;DR**

Only keep latest 10 backup folders via rsync

---

I am using rsync to backup my files onto a remote server OR another directory on the same machine as such:

```
SRC="${1}"
DEST="${2}"
PREFIX="$( date '+%Y-%m-%d__%H_%M_%S' )"

rsync --archive \
    --progress \
    --compress \
    --delete \
    --delete-excluded \
    --link-dest=../current \
    --delay-updates \
    --partial-dir=".partial-${PREFIX}" \
    "${SRC}" "${DEST}/${PREFIX}"
```

With this I will have the following directory structure after a few backups

```
$ ls ${DEST}/
2017-02-26__16_36_19/
2017-02-26__16_41_23/
2017-02-26__16_41_24/
2017-02-26__16_41_25/
current -> 2017-02-26__16_41_25/
```

`current` always points to the latest backup that has been done.

Now as I don't know if `$DEST` is either a local folder OR a remote server address, I would like to use `rsync` to always delete all other folders inside `$DEST` which are not the latest 10. So basically I just want to keep the latest 10 backup folders and remove the rest.

Is this somehow possible even though I don't know if the `rsync` script is triggered for a directory on the same machine or an ssh server address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rsync` has not such option ("delete all dirs older than..."), you had to achieve the same effect by using `ssh` and a custom script.

Even better, you can use [`rsnapshot`](http://rsnapshot.org/) to manage backup rotation and retention.

Comment: rdiff-backup is another popular alternative for rsync-like backups.