# rsync: rename destination folder after successfull rsync

Tags: rsync

Is it possible for `rsync` to rename its destination folder after successful run. So that I can always make sure the proper folder name always has a successful and complete backup?

**Example:**

rsync to folder `/backup/incomplete-2017-02-26` and after it finished synching to rename it to `/backup/2017-02-26`

**Update**

I need this for either local folders or remote folders.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rsync - only keep 10 backup folders](http://serverfault.com/questions/834994/rsync-only-keep-10-backup-folders)

Comment: both mine: The current one is about atomic writes and the other one about keeping X backups. I would say kind of different. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the return value of `rsync` - it will return `0` upon successful completion:

```
if rsync  -av source dest ; then 
   mv folder
else 
   echo "Something went wrong"
fi
```

The exit code is also available in the variable `$?` right after the command runs - beware, this will be overwritten by the next command.

Comment: The `rsync` destination could also be a remote address, so this won't work for all cases. I added that to the initial question to make it more clear

Comment: Why wouldn't this work for remote locations? If the transfer fails, `rsync` will exit with something else then `0`. If it suceeds, you can do something like `ssh user@host mv .... `

Comment: But how would the script know if rsync was done to a local path or an remote one? it should either be doing `mv` or `ssh ... mv`.

Comment: You could use flags for the script or you could look into the command (e.g. if the target contains a `:/` it is most likely remote)

Comment: Just as a small addition: `rsync  -av source dest && mv folder` may work as a shorter version of the above if (won't print out an error message though).

Comment: @Sven yes that could be a way to extract the host part by `:`. thanks